# getting 500 response after deploying symfony2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have been trying to deploy symfony2 on a shared hosting server, but I keep getting `500 response`.

All files under `web/` directory have been put in the `public_html` directory.

The other directories [`app` , `bin` , `src` and `vendor`] have been put at one level higher.

My directory structure look like this:

```
| -- /app
| -- /bin
| -- /src
| -- /vendor
| -- /public_html
```

I did clear the cache manually before to upload the file to the server.

**app.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sonata\PageBundle\Request\RequestFactory;
/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
#DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    #RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    #RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app_dev.php [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**composer.json**

```
 "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",

        "symfony-web-dir": "public_html",

        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
        }
    }
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="web directory">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public_html/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="app_php handling" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public_html/app.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: My guess is check the permissions but you should know more if you check the logs.

Comment: The folder `app/logs`  is empty and the folder `www_logs` doesn't contain any recent logs.

Comment: Check your server logs, not symfony ones

Comment: @vladkras, the server logs are located in `www_logs` but there is no any recent logs available.

Comment: The only error logs I have found is this : `[Fri May 26 19:02:28 2017] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /usr/www/users/ccacomkppe/public_html
[Fri May 26 19:02:29 2017] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /usr/www/users/ccacomkppe/public_html
[Fri May 26 19:02:29 2017] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /usr/www/users/ccacomkppe/public_html`

Comment: Please I still need some help

Comment: So where are your files? Do you really have them in `/usr/www/users/ccacomkppe`?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly common when your `cache` directory is not writable.

```
chmod 0755 /path/to/cache
```

or in some cases even:

```
chmod 0777 /path/to/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your server can't find your files.
Not sure about IIS, but you're missing some rules. take a look at https://gist.github.com/nurbek-ab/9c2997441fcaa2e52b0a

In nginx it's

root /var/www/project/web;

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}
```